# Low on oil and don't know why.

Tags: toyota

I heard a clicking noise, checked the oil,down 3 qts.,2011 Toyota pick up, no wet spots on the ground or the oil pan, no smoke. Where did the oil go?

Comment: Did you check the radiator?

Comment: Did you turn the engine off and let the oil settle before checking the oil level?

Comment: How long has it been, or how many miles have you driven since the last time you checked the oil prior to this?

Comment: Check the colour and smell of your exhaust, you may be burning the oil.